# Safe transport in Mexico City for a solo female travel (cheap too)

Tags: transportation, mexico-city

I am a solo female traveller and will be staying in Mexico City for 2 days by myself. I understand the main attraction is the historical centre area. I am considering 2 hotels.

a) One near the big circle on Paseo de la Reforma (this one has a swimming pool but is 4.5 km away from the historical centre).

b) One very close to the historical centre (no swimming pool but is 450 m away from the historical centre).

What transport can I use if I stay near Paseo de la Reforma if I want to go to the historical centre, and is it easy and safe to use?

Also if I stay near Paseo de la Reforma is there other stuff I can see that I could perhaps walk to? Like the museum of anthropology?

Answer (score 2):

Mexico City has a vast underground network.

Paseo de la Reforma is a long street, but if it's the circle I think, the closest stop would be Sevilla served by line 1, which takes you to Pino Suarez, near the historical centre

Comment: There is also some info about safety in Mexico city https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13303/getting-from-mexico-city-airport-to-downtown-easily-and-safely?rq=1 specifically about coming from the airport but i might help the OP.